# APC cache usage

Tags: php, caching, apc

I have to use APC cache just for opcode caching. so is it enough to just enable it from php.ini file with setting variable apc.stat to 'false'? I am already using memcache for object caching. do I need to use APC cache functions like apc_add, apc_fetch etc?

Comment: Yes just turn it on. And you don't need any new methods.

Comment: If you can, use ZendOpcache. It comes with PHP 5.5+